# Why lock_guard requires Lockable concept

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

It seems that BasicLockable concept is enough for lock_guard, but in the standard draft(N3242), Lockable is required for the Mutex template parameter. Any reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In n3290 (§30.4.2.1[thread.lock.guard]/1), it says,

> An object of type `lock_guard` controls the ownership of a lockable object within a scope. A `lock_guard` object maintains ownership of a lockable object throughout the `lock_guard` object’s lifetime (3.8). The behavior of a program is undefined if the lockable object referenced by `pm` does not exist for the entire lifetime of the `lock_guard` object. **The supplied `Mutex` type shall meet the `BasicLockable` requirements (30.2.5.2).**

The 2nd paragraph in n3242 is probably an editorial error. This is [library defect 2023: Incorrect requirements for `lock_guard` and `unique_lock`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2023),  and the paragraph is removed in n3290, as shown in [n3278: Recent Concurrency Issue Resolutions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3278.htm#2023.thread.lock.guard)